# How to make a local ContentView bind a Label text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, label, local

I made a ContentView with an Expander. I want to duplicate this Xaml code multiple times in an other Xaml file. But I want for each Expander a different Binding.
I linked this code (ContentView code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:expandable="clr-namespace:Expandable;assembly=ExpandableView"
             x:Class="Hello.ExpandableView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <expandable:ExpandableView Padding="5">
    <expandable:ExpandableView.PrimaryView>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5" CornerRadius="10">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="label" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Image Source="arrow.png" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25" Margin="5"/>
                </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
    </expandable:ExpandableView.PrimaryView>
    <expandable:ExpandableView.SecondaryViewTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5" CornerRadius="10">
        <Label Text="{Binding Tip1Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" Padding="5"/>
                </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </expandable:ExpandableView.SecondaryViewTemplate>
</expandable:ExpandableView>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

```
namespace Hello
{
    public partial class ExpandableView : ContentView
    {
        public static BindableProperty LabelProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Label),
                            typeof(string),
                            typeof(ExpandableView),
                            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => (b as ExpandableView).OnLabelChanged());

        private void OnLabelChanged()
        {
            label.Text = Label; //label is the x:Name of your Label control in ExpandableView.xaml
        }

        public string Label
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(LabelProperty);
            set => SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

To this code:
This works:

```
<local:ExpandableView Label="Hello"/>
```

But I want this. This does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:expandable="clr-namespace:Expandable;assembly=ExpandableView"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hello"
             x:Class="Hello.Health.HealthDetail"
             Title="{Binding Name}">
     <ContentPage.Content>
     <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Tip1Uitleg}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" Padding="10, 5, 10, 5"/>

            <local:ExpandableView Label="{Binding Tip1}"/> //This is what it is all about
</StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

CodeBehind:

```
namespace Hello.Health
{
    public partial class HealthDetail : ContentPage
    {
        public HealthDetail(HealthStrings healthStrings)
        {
            if (healthStrings == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            BindingContext = healthStrings;

            InitializeComponent();


        }
    }
}
```

How do I make this work? I have to make this above more dynamic, but I do not know how.

BTW This also works:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Tip1}" />
```

I am sorry for the unclear explanation, I hope someone can help me.
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind to 'this' since you are using a BindableProperty. Instead you should update the Label.Text property when the value of the BindableProperty changes.

```
public static BindableProperty LabelProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Label),
                            typeof(string),
                            typeof(ExpandableView),
                            propertyChanged:(b, o, n) => (b as ExpandableView).OnLabelChanged());

private void OnLabelChanged()
{
    label.Text = Label; //label is the x:Name of your Label control in ExpandableView.xaml
}

public string Label
{
    get => (string)GetValue(LabelProperty);
    set => SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourProject.ExpandableView">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="label"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with your code in ExpandableView.xaml.cs and added x:Name="label" in ExpandableView.xaml. But now I get a systemNullReferenceException. Can I keep <local:ExpandableView Label="{Binding Tip1}"/> the same? What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have edited my answer above including an example on the name that you have to add to the label. I would also suggest changing your Label property name. Should be something like LabelText or Text because you are setting the text which is a string not the actual Label control. Even this might be causing an issue. Yes you should use it like that <local:ExpandableView Label="{Binding Tip1}"/>. Also you removed the line ```BindingContext = this;``` right?

Comment: Yes I deleted BindingContext = this;  The systemNullReferenceException says "The object reference not set to an instance of an object".  Thx for your patience and help :)

Comment: Check where the exception is thrown because I am guessing it doesnt have to do with the code above. Could you share your ExpandableView.xaml and codebehind code?

Comment: If I change my ExpandableView.Xaml to a simple Label ( like in your code above), It still does not work. It still gives the same systemNullReferenceException.

Comment: There must be something wrong in the Page and the view model with which your page is binding. If you could share your page's and viewmodel's code I could provide more info. Where exactly is the exception thrown? Have you checked the call stack?

Comment: I set all the code above. I changed the code in my question. The exception is trown in
                            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => (b as ExpandableView).OnLabelChanged());

Comment: The exception is also trown at: label.Text = Label;

Comment: The error must be thrown because the Label control named "label" is inside the PrimaryView so when trying to update its text the label is null. You should have a reference to primaryview.label in order to set the Label's text.

Comment: You need to have a reference of the ExpandableView's PrimaryView inside your ExpandableView codebehind and then change the label text by calling primaryView.label.Text inside the OnLabelChanged() method. You are using a lot of nested controls and you should change the way your ExpandableView is implemented because its not optimal.

Comment: I just started coding a year ago on my own, so for me it is very hard to change al these things :(.  But I really appreciated your help :),

Comment: If you created the ExpandableView I would suggest starting with a new ExpandableView object and try to have the desired result with as less nested controls as possible. This implementation will cause issues down the line that you will eventually have to fix.

Comment: I put the ExpandableView.cs above. I used an Expandablview control from Github.

Comment: Sorry but it was confusing because you named your class ExpandableView and also the name of the GitHub component is called ExpandableView

Comment: Yes, I understand. It is confusing.

Comment: You should remove the bindableproperty and bind to a string property of the healthStrings object named PrimaryViewText for example. So your label should be ```<Label Text="{Binding PrimaryViewText}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you want to binding a value for binableproperty, you could try the code below:

**ExpandableView**: I make a simple contentview with the same binableproperty for you reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="XamarinDemo.Pages.ExpandableView">
   <ContentView.Content>
       <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="Hello"></Label>
          <Label x:Name="label"></Label>
       </StackLayout>
   </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class ExpandableView : ContentView
 {
    public static BindableProperty LabelProperty =
 BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Label),
                        typeof(string),
                        typeof(ExpandableView),
                        propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => (b as 
ExpandableView).OnLabelChanged());

    private void OnLabelChanged()
    {
        label.Text = Label; //label is the x:Name of your Label control in ExpandableView.xaml
    }

    public string Label
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(LabelProperty);
        set => SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
    }
    public ExpandableView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

 }
```

**Usage:**

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <local:ExpandableView Label="{Binding str}"></local:ExpandableView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
  {
    public string str { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        str = "okay";

        this.BindingContext = this;
     }
 }
```

[image]